# Visual Studio add-in : Context menu split

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, visual-studio-addins

I built a Visual Studio add-in and I have a context menu that shows in the code window. I have about 6 options and I want to break them up using lines. I can't seem to figure out how to insert a splitter line. I've tried a few different things but get exceptions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. CommandBarPopup.BeginGroup = true